# Fake Mouse (C# or C++)

Tags: c#, c++, mouse

I need a way to fake that a mouse is connected.
The problem: My HTPC (Windows 8) has no mouse connected and I wrote a program to simulate mouse input using my Xbox 360 Controller. This works just fine, the only problem is, that there is no cursor visible (I can move it, but I cant see it).
My guess is, that Windows doesn't show a cursor when there is no mouse connected, so I need a way to pretend that a mouse is connected to the PC.
Of course, if you know another way to make the cursor visible I would gladly take this solution as well.

Regards,
Hidden

Comment: Looks like a driver Problem to me.

Comment: Seems to me like something that should be done in the controller driver, but I guess that would mean writing one for your needs.

Comment: Turn on mouse keys (by default in my Win8, it's left control + left alt + numlock)

Comment: Thanks Soonts, that was the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Soonts the answer is to enable the mouse keys.
Either using the Accessibility Options or using the shortcut "alt + shift + numlock"

Answer (score 0):

This is going to mean registering an interrupt controller with the system.  The system looks at the keyboard and mouse from the system side and expose these events based on the application in focus.  You should start your search for system event or hardware managers.  This falls into the device driver.  You might also look at examples of mouse drivers.

[enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj128406%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)